# Javascript: Ecommerce add to cart function not working in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to write an **add to cart** functionality using Javascript and django (main functionality is Javascript).

I have written this code for the cart.js

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')
console.log("Working");

for (i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
    updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var productId = this.dataset.product
        var action = this.dataset.action
        console.log('productId is:', productId, 'Action is:', action)
        console.log('USER:', user)

    })
}
```

And this is the code for template
index.html

```
{% for product in products %}
{{ product.title }}
{{ product.price}}

<button data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
{% endfor %}
```

When i `print(product.id)` it gets the specific product id but the button does not wwork
what could be the problem with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you actually call that action?

```
for (i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
    updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var productId = this.dataset.product
        var action = this.dataset.action

        // I think that you need to call the action
        window[action](productId);

        console.log('productId is:', productId, 'Action is:', action)
        console.log('USER:', user)

    })
}
```

Comment: Do you mean in the cart.js?

Comment: I've edited my original post to try to make it more clear. Please check the comment inside the code